# I need to display the results for my forEach on my html

Tags: angularjs, foreach

I'm setting up an admin page for my website and I'm using a forEach to loop thru the table but I don't know how to display the result on the HTML. This is what I have:

```
(new LocationSvc()).$getLocations()
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.Locations = data.value;
      angular.forEach($scope.Locations, function (loc) {
        console.log(loc.Id +" " + loc.Name + " " + loc.PhoneNumber);
        locationList = loc.Id + " " + loc.Name + " " + loc.PhoneNumber;
      })
```

I want to display the ID, Name, and Phone Number on a list for later editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have `$scope.Locations` set in your JavaScript, you should just be able to access and loop over it with an `ng-repeat` in your html template associated with this controller.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Phone Number</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="loc in Locations">
            <td>{{loc.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{loc.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{loc.PhoneNumber}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```